# Why does arcpy.mapping.Layer give Runtime error: CreateObject Layer invalid data source?

Tags: arcpy, layers, layer-file

I want to connect an existing .lyr file to a variable defined as lyr2.

```
lyr2 = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"C:/Iso100Red.lyr")
```

Although it is a .lyr file, I get this Error code:

```
Runtime error <type 'exceptions.ValueError'>: Object: CreateObject Layer invalid data source
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: might be because '/' is not the valid path seperator for windows. You have to use '\', eg. "C:\Iso100Red.lyr". See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29

Comment: Forward slash is fine for Python on Windows.  I thought using raw (r) with forward slash (it is designed to avoid backslash being treated as an escape character) may have been the problem but I just tested and it worked fine at ArcGIS 10.2 with Python 2.7.3.

Comment: The error message isn't even that cryptic. Is says `Layer invalid data source`. This means the layer data is not valid. That means that when attempting to open the `.lyr` file ArcGIS was either unable to access the file or the data within was not valid Layer information.

Comment: I created the file straight out of ArcGis.So the data within should be ok.

Comment: to rephrase @PolyGeo: with `r` use backslash paths: `r"C:\Iso100Red.lyr"`, without `r` use foreslash: `"C:/Iso100Red.lyr"`. r stands for "raw".

Answer (score 4):

The file `C:\Iso100Red.lyr` does not exist or isn't a valid layer file.